# How to import prepopulated sqlite file to ios app and request query

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

i have a sqlite file on a server 
i want to connect to that server via objective-c on just after user successfully login to the application. then download the file to the bundle of app and then use it in other views.

First i want to ask is it possbile? if it is possible is there any tutorial or example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

There are many ways to download files from a server this is one of them:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.somewhere.com/thefile.sqlite";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.sqlite"];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Here is a tutorial for SQLite:
[SQLite Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. The file would can be stored in Application Document / Library directory.
The same can be achieved by using NSURLConnection.

A sample tutorial explaining NSURLConnection [tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/)

Hope this helps.